# Determine card in relation to card prefixes

Tags: javascript

```
var cards = new Array();

 cards [0] = {name: "VISA", length: "13,16", prefixes: "4", checkdigit: true};
 cards [1] = {name: "VISA_DELTA/ELECTRON", length: "16", prefixes: "417500,4844,4508,4026,4917,4913", checkdigit: true};
 cards [2] = {name: "MC", length: "16", prefixes: "51,52,53,54,55", checkdigit: true};
```

then my functions:

```
function CardTypes()
{
for (var i=0; i<cards.length; i++) {
if cards.name.Validate(PaymentForm.CardNumber.value)<!--pretty sure this is wrong-->
cardname = cards[i].getCardType();
}
if (cardname.length > 0) {
alert("This looks like a " + cardname + " .");
};
};
```

When the form is submitted it calls the Validate function which in turn calls all the other functions including CardTypes(). Id like to be able to determine the card type by the card prefixes i.e. 4 = visa. I'm pretty sure i have completely messed up the CardTypes() function. Any help would be appreciated. My form id is PaymentForm.

Comment: Before I go on into coding a solution, I must be sure of 2 things: 1) PaymentForm.CardNumber.value for sure will give the value given by the user and 2) You want CardTypes to return the name of the card type. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I cannot do much more without the HTML or those 2 details.

Comment: @Mamsaac: Thanks for your prompt response. Yes CardTypes should return the card type name ie visa etc. PaymentForm is my form and CardNumber is the id of the card number input field which it would need to check. ill add the html to the original message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function CardTypes()
{
    var givenValue = PaymentForm.CardNumber.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        var cardPrefixes = cards[i].prefixes.split(',');
        var leave = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < cardPrefixes.length; j++) {
            if (givenValue.indexOf(cardPrefixes[j]) === 0) {
                return cards[i].name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Just saw planetjones response. It should also work. Although I wouldn't recommend modifying String's prototype for something like this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help...ill let you know how i get on.

Answer (score 0):

What is `PaymentForm.CardNumber.value` set to?  Is it the whole number of the card?

```
var cardNumber = PaymentForm.CardNumber.value;
```

If that's right you would then want to read all the prefixes e.g.

```
   for (var i=0; i<cards.length; i++) {

      var prefixes= cards[i].prefixes;
      var prefixArray = prefixes.split(",");

         for(var j=0; j < prefixArray.length; j++) {

            if(cardNumber.startsWith(prefixArray[j])) {
               alert("Card Type is " + cards[i].name);
            }

          }  
   }
```

// Add this method to String

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str){
    return (this.indexOf(str) === 0);
}
```

JSFiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/KDTPX/`

Comment: Thanks for your help...ill let you know how i get on